# Do there exist any Phoenician or Etruscan dictionaries online?

Tags: resource-request, phoenician

I am trying to find a word list for Phoenician but [this](http://ancientroadpublications.com/Studies/AncientLanguage/Phoenician.pdf) is all I've found online (a short list, who knows how accurate it is). The only books (without previews unfortunately) I could find were these:

- [A Comparative Semitic Lexicon of the Phoenician and Punic Languages](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0891301267)
- [Phoenician-Punic dictionary](https://books.google.com/books/about/Phoenician_Punic_dictionary.html?id=bh_jdzIT9GQC) (OUT OF PRINT)

  > The Phoenician-Punic Dictionary is the most comprehensive word thesaurus of the Phoenician language yet collected and published, and a unique informational sourcebook for the Phoenician literature and culture.

That last one sounds promising but I can't see any demo. It looks like it's at the [Berkeley library](http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/search/o247963897) (yay), so maybe that's the only option. Does anyone have any experience with this, are there any resources online? I am specifically looking for glyph-sequences and their meaning.

Google is not showing me anything otherwise.

I am also looking for Etruscan dictionaries, but there is even less. Didn't find any books to reference, perhaps maybe [this](http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b15126939~S1) though. Has a nice review:

> This is the barest of bones when it comes to resources on the Etruscan language, printed and published in the cheapest way possible. The information it presents is scant at best, reading like it was a plagiarized Wikipedia article. I recommend The Etruscan Language: an Introduction by Bonfante instead. You'll actually get something out of that one.

I'm not used to there not being at least 5 or 10 online references :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Krahmalkov's *Phoenician-Punic Grammar* contains a high-quality (but unfortunately short) dictionary, focusing mostly on functional words and affixes rather than content words. It seems like it's meant to be used alongside a database of triconsonantal roots.

*EDIT: Krahmalkov also has a* Phoenician-Punic Dictionary *alongside the grammar, and I finally managed to get my hands on a digital copy. So I can say now, they're much more useful combined than separately.*

Glen Gordon (an amateur Etruscanist) used to maintain a [database](https://sites.google.com/site/paleoglot/Home/09417289.xml?attredirects=0) of all attested Etruscan word-forms with tentative translations. His translations don't always agree with the mainstream consensus, to put it lightly, and I'm not sure the database is still updated, but it's a great way to check if a particular form is attested or not.

As a side note, since you're "looking for glyph-sequences and their meaning"—I would highly recommend reading a grammar of the language, if possible, instead of just looking words up in a list. There's much more to a language than the meaning of each individual word; to translate coherently, you also need to understand the morphology, the syntax, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

For Etruscan, I suggest this:
https://diachronica.pagesperso-orange.fr/TMCJ_vol_3.2_Fournet_Etruscan.pdf
It's based on Bonfante and it's free :):)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no online dictionaries for Phoenician. To those two that you have already found *Dictionary of the North-West Semitic Inscriptions* by Hoftijzer and Jongeling can be added. But in it are data on other languages beside Phoenician.

Answer (score 1):

Archive.org has https://archive.org/details/richards.tombackacomparativesemiticlexiconzlib.org available for free download in .pdf format

Answer (score 0):

I found most of what is proposed here on archive.org or using the Doi number on sci-hub
https://sci-hub.se/10.1163/9789004294202

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj52s_98MnuAhVxQRUIHSVIAhUQFjADegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fprofile%2FNguyen_Trung_Hiep3%2Fpost%2FAre_there_any_inscriptions_in_Asia_similar_to_the_King_Asokas_Damma_Inscriptions%2Fattachment%2F59d62eb679197b807798ce65%2FAS%3A355380594003968%401461740745067%2Fdownload%2F%5BJ._Hoftijzer%2C_K._Johgeling%2C_Richard_C._Steiner%2C_B(Book4You).pdf&usg=AOvVaw0BEhfMApx8r6-gpc5ZVceJ